# How to get the general formula for this recursive problem containing flooring function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$a_2=a_1 +2=a_1+a_1$$
$$a_3=a_2 +2=a_2+a_1$$
$$a_4=a_3 +4=a_3+a_2$$

The pattern is $a_1=2,$ $a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{[\frac{n}{2}]}, n\geq 2$, where $ [\cdot ]$ is the floor function.

How to get the general formula of $a_n$?

I find $n=1,2,3, \ldots ,10$, then $a_n = 2,4,6,10,14,20,26,36,46,60$. But I don't know how to get the general formula.

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000123) is your friend.

Comment: I think if you consider two steps at once then you can get rid of the floor. So $a_{2n+2} = a_{2n} + a_n + a_{n+1}$. I'm not sure how to solve this though. I think this is a non-linear recurrence relation. Also, sorry about my incorrect answer (deleted). The pattern of the first few happens to be consistent with a Fibonacci sequence and I didn't look close enough.

Comment: @GohP.iHan This website is difficult for me to understand. Can you share any other tutorial ?

Comment: Per the OEIS record no closed form formula is known.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some valid formulae as $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{[\frac{n}{2}]}$ (using your notation) by taking a look at the "FORMULA" section of the OEIS sequence [A000123](https://oeis.org/A000123)

Comment: This website is difficult for me to understand. Can you share any other tutorial ?